# spring-data-mongo enable logging of query fired

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

When we use JPA we have `spring.jpa.show-sql=false` to enable logging of SQL statements.

How can enable logging of MongoDb queries on Spring Data JPA

Comment: Did you find answer?

Comment: Nope still don't have answer

Answer (score 3):

Just enable the DEBUG logging level for MongoTemplate on application.properties file...

logging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate=DEBUG